# Grails test: Cannot get property on null object

Tags: grails

I'm writing an integration test for a controller section with no inputs and a render statement - so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong but this throws a "Cannot get property 'appMessages' on null object" error.   I'm pretty new to testing, so sometimes I miss things that might seem easy. :)

Test:

```
@Test
void "test welcome"() {
    def ncpic = new IndexController()
    def model = ncpic.welcome()
    assertEquals 'welcome', model.appMessages.results       
}
```

Controller section:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
def welcome() {
    def crit = ApplicationMessage.createCriteria()
    def results = crit.listDistinct{
        or{
            isNull('messageInactivationDate')
            gt('messageInactivationDate', (new Date())) 
        } 
        lt('messageDate', new Date())
    }
    render(view:'welcome', model:[appMessages:results]) 
}
```

Comment: I posted examples below which show how to do this but the bottom line is that your test is trying to interact with the return value from the `welcome` method and expecting that to be the model.  Your welcome action is not returning a model.  Some controller actions do and your test would work for that style of action, but since your action doesn't return the model, your test is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong with your test.  One is that you should not be creating your own instance of the controller.  You should let the testing framework do that for you.  Second is you are expecting your welcome action to return the model, but it doesn't.  It calls the render method.  Something like the following should work.  This happens to be using a Spock Spec but you could do the same sort of thing in a JUnit test...

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(IndexController)
@Mock(ApplicationMessage)
class IndexControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        when:
        controller.welcome()

        then:
        'welcome' == model.appMessages.results
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**  Below is a JUnit example...

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(IndexController)
@Mock(ApplicationMessage)
class IndexControllerTests {

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        controller.welcome()

        // this assertion is still suspect, but that isn't
        // really what the question is about...
        assertEquals 'welcome', model.appMessages.results
    }
}
```

The relevant bit here is referring to the model property that is added to this class by the test mixin.  You can't refer to the return value of the welcome method given the way that your controller action is written.  The action is written fine, but the test needs to be written in a way that is compatible with that, as shown above.

Comment: The assertion there matches the one in the original post, but it looks suspicious to me.  That looks suspicious because appMessages is going to be a List of ApplicationMessage objects.  That is probably going to be a separate problem, but I expressed the same assertion in the solution that you expressed in your code.

Comment: You are going to end up with a list of results so referring to `appMessages.results` and expecting that to be a String doesn't really make sense. That is however unrelated to your original question about the null reference.  That is caused by expecting the welcome method to return a Map, which it does not.

Comment: I'm doing it JUnit; I have a local database to run against.

Comment: JUnit is fine.  The idea is still the same.  I will post an example which shows how to do this in a JUnit test.

Comment: Note that these tests would be defined under `test/unit/`, not `test/integration`.

Comment: might have figured it out or close to it -- this may be on the right track...     @Test
 void "test welcome"() {
     controller.welcome()
     assert view == "/index/welcome"
  assert model.appMessages != null 
  assert model.appMessages.size() == 2
 }

Comment: Yes.  The key is you want to refer to the model property added to your test by the mixin.  In your original test you are referring to your own local variable called `model` which is assigned the return value of your call to the `welcome` action, which does not return the model.

Comment: The assertion in your original test appears bogus, but that is not relevant to the question you asked which is about getting a property on a null object.  That problem is caused by referring to the `model` variable that you assigned the return value of your controller action.  It sounds like you have it sorted out now.

Answer (score 0):

I usually test like:

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class FirstControllerSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

  FirstController controller

  def setup() {
    controller = new FirstController()
  }

  def cleanup() {
  }

  void "test something"() {
    when:
    controller.welcome()

    then:
    assert controller.modelAndView.viewName == "/first/welcome"
    assert controller.modelAndView.model.size() == 1
    assert controller.modelAndView.model.appMessages != null
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason for this to be an integration test.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - In the question mentioned that integration that's why I posted a integration test. I am also new in testing, just few weeks, may I know is any thing wrong in my test case. Thanks

Comment: Integration tests require a lot more of the framework runtime to be initialized and his test isn't covering anything that requires any of that, so there is no reason to pay that price.  His test is very simple and there is nothing in his test or his description which calls for an integration test.